# In View Pager displayed only last Images from Json repeatedly in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-viewpager, android-imageview

I am having problem to displaying images for Image Slider in android.I am fetching the images from JSON but always displaying last image of index only, Suppose if i can move the View Pager same image again and again displaying for image sliding in Android.
    I don't know what is the problem, I tried almost as i can but i really couldn't find that error.
    Anyone help to solve my problem.

CODE:

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_zoomproduct_);
     options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
         .showStubImage(R.drawable.b2)
         .showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.b2)
         .showImageOnFail(R.drawable.b2)
         .build();


     /********************  this is for single page product ***********************/

     Intent singleproductpage = getIntent();
     singlepro = singleproductpage.getStringExtra("currentinedx");
     Intent multipleimages = getIntent();
     multipleimg = multipleimages.getStringExtra("multipleimages");
     Intent productpath = getIntent();
     productpaths = productpath.getStringExtra("productpath");
     Intent seller = getIntent();
     sellers = seller.getStringExtra("sellerid");
     //  pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Zoomproduct_Activity.this);
     //   pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
     //   pDialog.setCancelable(false);
     singleproduct();
     viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
     // Pass results to ViewPagerAdapter Class
     adapter = new ZoomAdapter(Zoomproduct_Activity.this, adlist);
     // Binds the Adapter to the ViewPager
     viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
     adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
 }

multipleimage = new JSONArray(multiimg);
if (multipleimage.length() > 0) {
     for (int i = 0; i < multipleimage.length(); i++) {

         JSONObject singleimg = multipleimage.getJSONObject(i);
         /*oneimg = singleimg.getString("original_res");
         String singleImages= productpath+sid+ '/'+ oneimg;*/
         // zoom.setImageUrl(productpaths+sellers+ '/'+singleimg.getString("original_res"));
         // imgs.add(zoom);
         String imagesone = productpaths + sellers + '/' + singleimg.getString("original_res");
         map.put(TAG_IMAGE, imagesone);
         adlist.add(map);
         String imgs1 = String.valueOf(adlist);
         //String zoom1=String.valueOf(imgs1);
         // Log.d(zoom1,"zoom");
         Log.d(imgs1, "ararlist");

    }
}
```

Adapter:

```
public class ZoomAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
    LayoutInflater inflator;
    ImageView imgDisplay;
    Context context;
    //  ArrayList<ZoomimageModel> slideShowImages;
    //  ArrayList<String> slideShowImages;
    private ArrayList < HashMap < String, String >> slideShowImages;
    HashMap < String, String > plotimages;

    DisplayImageOptions options;

    public ZoomAdapter(Context context, ArrayList < HashMap < String, String >> slideShowImages) {
        this.context = context;
        this.slideShowImages = slideShowImages;
        options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
            .showStubImage(R.drawable.slip1)
            .showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.b2)
            .showImageOnFail(R.drawable.ic_drawer)
            .build();
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return slideShowImages.size();
    }
    public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
        return POSITION_NONE;
    }


    // @Override
    /*  public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
          return view == ((ImageView) object);
      }*/

    //    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, final int position) {
        inflator = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View viewLayout = inflator.inflate(R.layout.productzoomrow, container,
            false);
        imgDisplay = (ImageView) viewLayout.findViewById(R.id.imgDisplay);
        // ZoomimageModel zooms=slideShowImages.get(position);
        plotimages = slideShowImages.get(position);

        // System.out.println("ImageUrl---------------------"+slideShowImages.get(position).getImageUrl());
        System.out.println("ImageUrl---------------------" + plotimages.get(Zoomproduct_Activity.TAG_IMAGE));
        //  YelloPage.imageLoader.displayImage(zooms.getImageUrl(), imgDisplay, options);
        YelloPage.imageLoader.displayImage(plotimages.get(Zoomproduct_Activity.TAG_IMAGE), imgDisplay, options);

        container.addView(viewLayout);
        return viewLayout;
    }



    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        // ((ViewPager) container).removeView((ImageView) object);
        (container).removeView((RelativeLayout) object);
        // container.removeView((View) object);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return view == object;
    }


    /* @Override
     public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object)
     {
         ((ViewPager) container).removeView((ImageView) object);
     }*/
}
```

Logcat showimages:

```
[05 - 07 02: 06: 15.445 26970: 26970 D / [{
                original_res = http: //192.168.0.33/cartwebsite3/cdn-images/prd/1/lenovo-a6000-171452579105.jararlist

                    [05 - 07 02: 06: 15.445 26970: 26970 D / [{
                                original_res = http: //192.168.0.33/cartwebsite3/cdn-images/prd/1/lenovo-a6000-791452579106.jararlist

                                    [05 - 07 02: 06: 15.445 26970: 26970 D / [{
                                                original_res = http: //192.168.0.33/cartwebsite3/cdn-images/prd/1/lenovo-a6000-971452579106.jararlist

                                                    [05 - 07 02: 06: 15.445 26970: 26970 D / [{
                                                                original_res = http: //192.168.0.33/cartwebsite3/cdn-images/prd/1/lenovo-a6000-341452579106.jararlist

                                                                    [05 - 07 02: 06: 15.445 26970: 26970 D / [{
                                                                                original_res = http: //192.168.0.33/cartwebsite3/cdn-images/prd/1/lenovo-a6000-891452579106.jararlist

                                                                                    [05 - 07 02: 06: 15.445 26970: 26970 D / [{
                                                                                                original_res = http: //192.168.0.33/cartwebsite3/cdn-images/prd/1/lenovo-a6000-441452579106.jararlist
                                                                                                    05 - 07 02: 06: 15.445 26970 - 26970 / com.journaldev.navigationdrawer D / lenovo - a6000 - 171452579105. jpeg: images
                                                                                                05 - 07 02: 06: 15.445 26970 - 26970 / com.journaldev.navigationdrawer D / lenovo - a6000 - 791452579106. jpeg: images
                                                                                                05 - 07 02: 06: 15.446 26970 - 26970 / com.journaldev.navigationdrawer D / lenovo - a6000 - 971452579106. jpeg: images
                                                                                                05 - 07 02: 06: 15.446 26970 - 26970 / com.journaldev.navigationdrawer D / lenovo - a6000 - 341452579106. jpeg: images
                                                                                                05 - 07 02: 06: 15.446 26970 - 26970 / com.journaldev.navigationdrawer D / lenovo - a6000 - 891452579106. jpeg: images
                                                                                                05 - 07 02: 06: 15.446 26970 - 26970 / com.journaldev.navigationdrawer D / lenovo - a6000 - 441452579106. jpeg: images
                                                                                                05 - 07 02: 06: 15.448 754 - 7094 / system_process V / WindowManager: Adding window Window {
                                                                                                    39992643 u0 com.journaldev.navigationdrawer / com.journaldev.navigationdrawer.Activity.Zoomproduct_Activity
                                                                                                }
                                                                                                at 4 of 9(after Window {
                                                                                                    2 fb8c08e u0 com.journaldev.navigationdrawer / com.journaldev.navigationdrawer.Activity.singleshooppingcart
                                                                                                })
                                                                                                05 - 07 02: 06: 15.464 26970 - 26970 / com.journaldev.navigationdrawer I / System.out: ImageUrl-- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- - http: //192.168.0.33/cartwebsite3/cdn-images/prd/1/lenovo-a6000-441452579106.jpeg
                                                                                                    05 - 07 02: 06: 15.477 26970 - 26970 / com.journaldev.navigationdrawer I / System.out: ImageUrl-- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- - http: //192.168.0.33/cartwebsite3/cdn-images/prd/1/lenovo-a6000-441452579106.jpeg
                                                                                                    05 - 07 02: 06: 15.535 26970 - 27049 / com.journaldev.navigationdrawer W / EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
                                                                                                05 - 07 02: 06: 15.536 26970 - 27049 / com.journaldev.navigationdrawer W / OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xe2266e00,
                                                                                                error = EGL_SUCCESS
                                                                                                05 - 07 02: 06: 15.792 754 - 780 / system_process I / ActivityManager: Displayed com.journaldev.navigationdrawer / .Activity.Zoomproduct_Activity: +358 ms
                                                                                                05 - 07 02: 06: 16.062 715 - 715 / ? W / SurfaceFlinger : couldn 't log to binary event log: overflow.
                                                                                                05 - 07 02: 06: 20.092 26970 - 26970 / com.journaldev.navigationdrawer I / System.out: ImageUrl-- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- - http: //192.168.0.33/cartwebsite3/cdn-images/prd/1/lenovo-a6000-441452579106.jpeg
                                                                                                    05 - 07 02: 06: 20.256 754 - 1067 / system_process D / WifiService: acquireWifiLockLocked: WifiLock {
                                                                                                        NlpWifiLock type = 2 binder = android.os.BinderProxy @997c048
                                                                                                    }
```

Glad to appreciate to solve my problem

Comment: Can you explain why you are using `ArrayList` of `HashMap` instead you just use `ArrayList` of `String` and get the `image` by position.

Comment: Problem in your code is that you are using the same `IMAGE_TAG` for each image, so the last image added to the `HashMap` will be displayed

Comment: Before i don't use HashMap i used model to set and get image, but  that one is also i got same images

Comment: You get my point ? As you are using the same `Key` in the `HashMap` for Images, it is returning you the last image, just try to log `HashMap` size it will be 1

Comment: How to change my code to get all the images can u please tell me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the `ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>` to `ArrayList<String>` as it seems `HashMap` is not required from your code.

Next in your `for` loop you where you are adding image path to `HashMap` instead add that directly to `ArrayList`,

And then in `getView()` of your `PagerAdapter` get the image from `ArrayList<>` using `slideShowImages.get(position)`,

Comment: Thanks buddy,really Thanks a lot ,I did small mistake got headache.

Comment: Great . Happy to help :)

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: Its not a good practice to add answer to explain what is problem instead do one thing post a new question or update this question with the details :)

Comment: Thanks for your comments buddy